# zebra stripped with round corners not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css, zebra-striping

I have a several list on my site: [URL Link](http://www.swedishpunkfanzines.com/?page_id=1522)

It got zebra stripped background. In Chrome I also get rounded corners which look nice but in Firefox it does not work. I have looked at endless help site without success. The only thing I have learned is that rounded corners is not working when "border-collapse is set to collapse" but I found a way around that. However - it still does not work.... driving me mad...

This is the CSS I currently use:

```
* TABLES CODES
--------------------------------------- */

table.zebra {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate; 



}

.zebra td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left; 


}

.zebra tr td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

}

.zebra tr td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

}



.zebra tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #F0F0F0!important;
    color:#000;

}
```

Comment: My solution would be to not use tables...  This isn't tabular data, and the very same visual effect can be achieved with <div>'s

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am stuck with these tables. I have no problem with rounded corners in general in Firefox, it just inside tables I can't get it to work.

Comment: I just noticed that your background color is being applied to TR's and not TD's, yet the TD's are what have the rounded edges.  See my answer below, comment on it when you have tried that if it doesnt work and I will take another look.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this bit of CSS:

```
.zebra tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #F0F0F0!important;
    color:#000;

}
```

to this...

```
.zebra tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background: #F0F0F0!important;
    color:#000;

}
```

Comment: Wow. I understand. It did magic. This expains why the few cases I got rounded corners by addting boarder-right etc code below I cound see the background "outside" the corners. .zebra tr td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;